# Rails 4 - how is the "/tmp" cleaned?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, sidekiq, tmp

I am generating PDF document and storing it temporarily to the `/tmp` directory. Once the document is generated and stored in the directory (I am doing it as a background process with Sidekiq), then I upload it to Amazon S3 and delete it from the `/tmp` directory.

What I noticed is that when a user generate a document and I am deploying some new code to the server (with using Capistrano), the process of generating/uploading document is interrupted.

I was wondering if this might be related to Sidekiq? It's running as an Upstart service on Ubuntu, so I don't think so.

Then I thought the problem might be that I am storing the document in the `/tmp` directory. How the directory works? Is the whole content of the directory deleted when I do a new deployment with Capistrano?

**EDIT:**

The document generation takes usually takes 5-10 seconds, but the queue is `default`, so the process might fail because there's too many `default` processes in the queue?

Comment: `/tmp` directory cleaned after every reboot.

Comment: `capistrano creates separate folder for every newly deployed code

Comment: @illusionist ok, so when I start generating the file, it's saved to `/tmp` and in this moment when I start deploying a code, this `/tmp` folder will become unaccessible for the application, am I right?

Comment: the `uploads/tmp` will now point to another `somrelease/public/uploads/tmp`

Answer (score 1):

The `/tmp` directory should be cleaned only during server boot (as @Зелёный already commented). But your PDF generation / upload **might just take too long** and the process might get killed. This is documented [here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Signals#sidekiqctl) and I quote from the docs:

> ```
> sidekiqctl stop [pidfile] 60
> ```
>
> This sends TERM, waits up to 60 seconds and then will kill -9 the Sidekiq process if it has not exited by then. Keep in mind the deadline timeout is the amount of time sidekiqctl will wait before running kill -9 on the Sidekiq process.

The details should be shown in the console output during the capistrano deployment, so if it's not the case of process getting killed, please add the output to the question.

Comment: Thanks @BoraMa, so what can I think of as about the solution? I think I should probably set creating PDF as the highest priority, right? Because right now, all Sikdeiq processes are `default`. Also, should I select a different directory where I would store the temporarily files before they're uploaded to AWS S3? Or actually, is the `/tmp` directory suitable for this task?